# Speaker went off - Xperia L

Tags: audio, speaker, sony-xperia-l

The loud speaker of my phone, Xperia L is off. I guess the headset plugged in event is triggered and so mutes the loud speaker. Can I do anything about it. I can't even answer or makes calls... have to put it on loudspeaker or plug in the headphones. I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Comment: Why don't you think it's a hardware issue? That's the most likely cause.

Comment: That's because, it plays all the notifications and as I said, when I speak on the phone, when I turn on the loudspeaker, it plays. My guess is though I unplug the headset, the unplugged event is not triggered.

Comment: Does it work after a reboot (and before you plug in your headset)? Have you checked your volume settings for the specific channels (could be the "headset plugged" simply overrides some "mute" here, and restores it on "unplug")?

Comment: @Izzy, I have rebooted many times and still the problem persisted. And the volume settings, I have used Perist+ app to check the volumes. No use. :|

Comment: Was worth a check, though. If there's no sound at all (except for the "loud speakers"), I tend to go with @DanHulme then, assuming a hardware problem. Two thing left to try: [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info).